# Floating popup window - how to implement

Tags: android, user-interface

I would like to have the following screen in my application: button at the bottom of the screen; when user presses the button, a list with a number of items will appear and user should be able to click one of those to start another activity. The number of items can be different (depending on some other conditions);  the popup is to be adjusted to the button. How would you suggest implementing this?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: One of the options is PopupWindow. Is there anything better than that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PopupWindow is great for that. Here's a nice sample http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) or [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

or you may also consider using [spinners](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html).

Answer (score 0):

[How to implement Drag and Drop in android 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306243/how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-in-android-2-2/14491467#14491467)

```
TextView view = new TextView(mActivity);
view.setText("asdasd");
popoup = new PopupWindow(view, 100, 100);
        popoup.setWindowLayoutMode(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        // set window at position
        popoup.showAtLocation(mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView(), Gravity.CENTER, 100, 100);

popoup.update();
```

What is usefull to know:

0 setContentView

1 Definetly you must tell popup size 
( 0 and 1 is contructor `new PopupWindow(view, 100, 100);` )

2 an on which location it will be show

3 and call update()