# Drag and Drop from list view to a layout in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to drag an image from list view and drop it on a linear layout and not on another list View.
I tried for this and I am able to drag an image from a list view and drop it on another list view but I want to set it on a layout ...
Please help me out..
thanks in advance

Comment: may be my code will you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306243/how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-in-android-2-2/11431727#11431727

Comment: As of Android 4.0 Drag and Drop of Views is supported. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html