# Drag image on imageview or set on another imageview in android

Tags: android

How to drag image on one imageview or set on another image view in android,I use one drag drop function but it is not correctly work?

Please solve my problems early.

Comment: post your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`This`](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html) tutorial is exactly what you are asking for. THere are [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306243/how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-in-android-2-2/11431727#11431727) SO posts also having correct answers to this