# Drag and Drop In relativelayout

Tags: java, android

I have very limited knowledge on both java and android programming (not from prog background). So please explain in laymen term if possible. Basically, I'm trying to make a mahjong tiles which I can move around as I like. I want to solve following problems:

1. I've set up an initial layout for my buttons (at the bottom of screen) through XML. While dragging button, the button will jump to top of the screen. I tried using .getX() instead of .getRawX(), but the button will move in a messed up pattern. And the emulator is very slow.
2. How can I set boundary for each of the button I've created? as in I don't want to have the button overlap among each other while I drag over one of them. So this mean that if I move tile A over tile B, tile B will try to avoid the overlap by moving away (or better idea, see no 3).
3. Need an general idea how to make the button to align with each other when they're close enough. Means when I move tile A closer to tile B, tile A will arrange side by side with tile B. I don't want them to be connected together (just aligned), and can easily break them by just moving any tiles away.

here's the code on drag and drop, I took reference from someone in this forum:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();  
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();      

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                xDelta = X - Params.leftMargin;
                yDelta = Y - Params.topMargin;

             break;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             break;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
             break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
             break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
              //restrict image from going over the screen boundary

              if ( (X - xDelta <= -5 || X - xDelta >= 390 ) ||
                   (Y - yDelta <= -5 || Y - yDelta >= 630 ) 
                  )
                  break;


              //Goes back to default drag and drop sequence
              else {
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
              layoutParams.leftMargin = X - xDelta;
              layoutParams.topMargin = Y - yDelta;          
              layoutParams.rightMargin = -10;
              layoutParams.bottomMargin = -10;

              view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
              break;
              }
      }

      environment.invalidate();
      return true;  
}
```

Comment: I'd subclass a layout, override onLayout() to place the tiles as I like ... and have the drag-drop framework do the rest...http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html. Use it, it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

drag and drop in android 2.2

here i give my code which give you the success.My Main Class is Here

```
package info.tempDD;
 import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

   public class TempDDActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        private View selected_item = null;
        private int offset_x = 0;
        private int offset_y = 0;
        Boolean touchFlag=false;
        boolean dropFlag=false;
        LayoutParams imageParams;
        ImageView imageDrop,image1,image2;
        int crashX,crashY;
        Drawable dropDrawable,selectDrawable;
        Rect dropRect,selectRect;
        int topy,leftX,rightX,bottomY;



int dropArray[];    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
        imageDrop=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgDrop);       
        image1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);      
        image2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);
        container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                if(touchFlag==true)
                {
                    System.err.println("Display If  Part ::->"+touchFlag);
                    switch (event.getActionMasked()) 
                    {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :

                         topy=imageDrop.getTop();
                         leftX=imageDrop.getLeft();
                         rightX=imageDrop.getRight();   
                         bottomY=imageDrop.getBottom();
                        System.err.println("Display Top-->"+topy);      
                        System.err.println("Display Left-->"+leftX);
                        System.err.println("Display Right-->"+rightX);
                        System.err.println("Display Bottom-->"+bottomY);                


                        //opRect.
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        crashX=(int) event.getX();
                        crashY=(int) event.getY();
                        System.err.println("Display Here X Value-->"+crashX);
                        System.err.println("Display Here Y Value-->"+crashY);

                        int x = (int) event.getX() - offset_x;
                        int y = (int) event.getY() - offset_y;                                          
                        //int w = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() - 100;
                        //int h = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() - 100;
                        int w = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() - 50;
                        int h = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() - 10;
                        if (x > w)
                            x = w;
                        if (y > h)
                            y = h;                      
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        lp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);                  

                        //Drop Image Here                       
                        if(crashX > leftX && crashX < rightX && crashY > topy && crashY < bottomY )                     
                        {                           
                            Drawable temp=selected_item.getBackground();                            
                            imageDrop.setBackgroundDrawable(temp);
                            imageDrop.bringToFront();                           
                            dropFlag=true;
                            selected_item.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                        //Drop Image Here                       
                        selected_item.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        break;  
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        //                      
                        touchFlag=false;
                        if(dropFlag==true)
                        {
                            dropFlag=false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            selected_item.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
                        }                       
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }else
                {
                    System.err.println("Display Else Part ::->"+touchFlag);
                }               
                return true;
            }
        });

        image1.setOnTouchListener(this);
        image2.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {   
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) 
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchFlag=true;
            offset_x = (int) event.getX();
            offset_y = (int) event.getY();
            selected_item = v;
            imageParams=v.getLayoutParams();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            selected_item=null;
            touchFlag=false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }       
        return false;
    }
}
```

After This create one class and Extend your main Layout like RelativeLayout

```
package info.tempDD;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class TouchInterceptor extends RelativeLayout {
    public TouchInterceptor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

}
```

And the Main My Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImgDrop"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11431727/2771869